# How to add multiple css files in grunt-css?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, optimization, gruntjs

I am using [grunt-uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) to remove redundant css from my project. For every HTML page referencing different css files, I am trying to create one css file for every html page. Here I am showing only two files but for real I am working with around 370 files. Here is my current code

```
 uncss: {
    dist: {
      files: 
        { 

'./newcss/75.css': ['./4dlife/src/app/views/com/twenty/todoPido.html'],

'./newcss/351.css': ['./4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html']
},
      options: {
        compress:true
      }
    }
  }
  });
```

However, the `todoPido.html` has no css files and hence my output is

> Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task 
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
>   file:///home/pc009/code/4dlife_repo/4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html:35
>   Fatal error: UnCSS: no stylesheets found

However when I run this

```
  uncss: {
    dist: {
      files: 
        { 

'./newcss/351.css': ['./4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html']
},
      options: {
        compress:true
      }
    }
  }
  });
```

I am getting the proper output for the `index.html`.

> Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task 
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
>   file:///home/pc009/code/4dlife_repo/4dlife/tools/experiments/index.html:35
>   File ./newcss/351.css created: 101.86 kB → 14.62 kB
>
> Done, without errors.

What I can not understand is what am I doing wrong. It works fine when I give one file but fails when I add multiple files. What am I doing wrong? And also, how to remove the `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`?