# grunt-uncss - multiple css files

Tags: gruntjs, uncss

I wrote simple code, which remove unused css rules with `grunt-uncss` task:

```
uncss:
  main:
    files:
        'src/css/style.css': 'src/**/*.html'
```

Is it possible to use it with multiple css files? I mean something like this:

```
uncss:
  main:
    files:
        'src/css/**/*.css': 'src/**/*.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know...

You can configure it to sift all the css loaded by many html files into a single CSS file they can all use, or you can have it create a unique CSS file for each HTML page.

To do the later, there is some code in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565476/how-to-add-multiple-css-files-in-grunt-css) that will help

I'm still learning this tool. Perhaps there is a way to have it load many HTML files and their attached CSS and output multiple CSS files that are all sifted that will work in the original structure.